# $_FILES only includes the last input

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I've been wrestling with this all day and am tired of being stuck. Spent half an hour this morning doing a nice little custom uploader for profile pictures on the same app that I'm now stuck on.

The issue here isn't uploading (I had that down), but expanding it to a form that allows for multiple uploads. It's not a multiple file, single input uploader, but rather has multiple inputs.

I currently only have two instances of `input type='file'` in the form. I'm using Codeigniter, but the issue isn't CI's inability to process multiple uploads (I don't think). All I'm trying to do now is simply do `print_r($_FILES);` which only shows the **second** of the two inputs.

If I swap them in their placement within the form it still only shows whichever one is last instead of both.

I've checked their names, etc. about 100x already today. Really unsure what's going on. And, to be clear, I have been searching the hell out of SO and Google to see if I can find the problem. So far I've come up with nothing.

Thanks for any guidance or help.

EDITS:----------------------------

```
<form action="http://curvo:8888/index.php/offers/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="bigolform" id="offer-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">                  
                    ...
                    <input type="file" name="ProductOfferPhoto" value="" id="ProductOfferPhoto">                    

                    ...

                    <input type="file" name="QuoteDoc" value="" id="QuoteDoc">                      

                    <!--using an ajax uploading script-->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>


                    <a href="#" class="orange btn add submit-the-offer">Complete offer</a>

</form>
```

I've tried using `genericName[]` as well, but that only gets me an empty array.

Comment: Please post HTML code

Comment: Also helpful would be the output of `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: What is the `name` of your Input Field? Sounds like you need it to be an array like `name=yourFieldName[]`

Comment: Can you fire up the request in a step debugger and halt before CI kicks into action? Which values are in `$_FILES` then. It might be that CI is wrangling superglobals somewhere. IIRC it does at leat with POST and GET, probably as well with `$_FILES`? You can easily find out with a debugger.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your input `name` is an array if you are accepting multiple files:

Single upload:
`<input name="productImage" accept="image/*" type="file" />`

Multiple uploads:
`<input name="productImage[]" accept="image/*" type="file" />`
`<input name="productImage[]" accept="image/*" type="file" />`
...
--------------------------------------^ The `[]` signifies this is an array and allows you to submit multiple values for the same name.

Then you will find multiple values for `$_FILES` instead of only the last file uploaded (as each file is basically overriding the last currently)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas and input, everyone. I don't know the answer regarding a solution, but I found the answer of "why" concerning the problem.

The ajaxfileuploader.js script I had grabbed off of Nettuts was throwing things. It worked fine for a while when I had the single upload but as soon as I started trying to do multiples it brooke down and only grabbed the very last `input` field.

Will be exploring the jQuery File Upload plugin by blueimp sometime in the near future. For now just going to skip out of ajax'ing it in order to meet the deadline I have for Monday.

Thanks again for the help.